# Struts 2 FileUpload in EC2 Glassfish 3 deployed not working

Tags: file-upload, struts2, amazon-ec2

I have spent numerous hours searching for a solution to this, not sure where else to turn. Our main app is deployed on amazon EC2, GlassFish 3.1. One of our pages handles file uploads. It works fine on my local development box, and on several other local deployments and other developer boxes. I've done a number of different logging options, and every time on local boxes the changed logging options appear correctly.

The problem is, no matter what I've tried, in amazon EC2, the file when uploaded never shows up in the various temporary paths I've tried (including changing all permissions to the path and parent paths to 777.. bad.. I know but trying anything to get this to work), the file always shows empty, and the logging indicates no errors. I've modified the file types allowed, the max file size supported, to no avail.

At this point, I am thinking it has something to do with EC2, since it works in several other deployments in different networks (team in India, local box, etc). I can't find anything in the EC2 console that sheds any light on any changes needed to permit a file upload. Heck, I can scp the .war file up to the instance and deploy it just fine, so I can't imagine anything would block file uploads from the web app itself from a browser.

Any help at all is much appreciated as this is unfortunately the only thing holding up our initial alpha release.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not EC2, but configuration. You mention files are created, but empty. Does your application use specific port for file uploads?

Comment: any clue in log file ? just see the log when u click on the file upload and see anything is there?? probably i suspect some kind of configuration issue

Comment: Hi.. no files make it up. In the specified tmp folder, nothing is there. On my local box they show up, but on our EC2 instance, nothing at all, and the log output shows no exceptions, errors, etc. My action class method is being called, but it reports null for all objects (File, filename, contentType). I am not too knowledgeable about struts 2 interceptor/stack order, not sure if I can add a more detailed debug interceptor that may give me more info about file upload issues? I am using annotations in my code, not the struts.xml file for configuring actions and results.

Comment: @Roman.. not sure how you would configure a port for file upload? It is just a typical <s:form..> with multipart specified. I assume that uses HTTP? I've not found anything indicating you would need to open yet another port to allow for file uploads? I set 755 on all folders from parent on down where files would be uploaded to.

Comment: @user1550090: its not you always see some error/exception there might be some validation or something else inside your interceptor stack which might be causing the issue,my suggestion is to have a deep look at log file and you can even set log level to info or debug for the time being

Comment: Is there a way to monitor/see the incoming http request for glassfish? That would at least let me see if the file makes it over.

Comment: Any chance this is a Fedora instance?  I've seen SELinux cause issues of this nature.